# Maven code coverage

Tags: java, maven, instrumentation, war

I am new to java world. Our team is using Maven to building everything into single .war file. I am looking for tools to instrument .war files to enable code coverage. Idea is to manually instrument .war file and then run the test.

I looked at couple of tools, but not getting exactly what I am looking for e.g. Emma, jester, cobertura etc. Looking for simple instructions.

Comment: Maven is very good build tool. Is there any specific reason to look for new tool?..

Comment: I want to know how to instrument it for code coverage build using Maven.

Comment: Instrument .war file??? Normally you'd run maven test on your project, if 100% pass then proceed with mvn package, which will build your war file. Code coverage fits in with the maven test step. You could store the html reports, integrate the stats and only proceed to package step if say lines covered > 90%. I use cobertura on my Grails projects, Emma on my Java/groovy projects. Very simple to install/use. Don't re-invent the wheel!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to measure code coverage you should use Jacoco. It allows measuring for unit tests and integration tests as well.

All you have to do is to add dependecy:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupid>org.jacoco</groupid>
    <artifactid>org.jacoco.core</artifactid>
    <version>0.6.2.201302030002</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

and add jacoco-maven-plugin. Please note that if you won't use Sonar then you have to replace ${sonar.jacoco.reportPath} properties with raw file paths

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.6.2.201302030002</version>
  <executions>
    <!-- prepare agent for measuring unit tests -->
    <execution>
      <id>prepare-unit-tests</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
      </configuration>
    </execution>

    <!-- prepare agent for measuring integration tests -->
    <execution>
      <id>prepare-integration-tests</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <configuration>
        <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
        <propertyName>itCoverageAgent</propertyName>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

If you want also to use sonar, then specify such properties:

```
<properties>
  <!-- select JaCoCo as a coverage tool -->
  <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
  <!-- force sonar to reuse reports generated during build cycle -->
  <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
  <!-- set path for unit tests reports -->
  <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco-unit.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
  <!-- all modules have to use the same integration tests report file -->
  <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
</properties>
```

You can find more details on http://www.kubrynski.com/2013/03/measuring-overall-code-coverage-in.html

Answer (score 1):

Cobertura would support that. See the answer to this question.

[Java: measure code coverage for remote scripting tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660141/java-measure-code-coverage-for-remote-scripting-tests)

If you want to do this in development rather than on your build server, you might want to give eclemma a try. You can launch your webapp in your IDE with eclemma and then simply run whatever test you want to run (outside of eclemma) and it will nicely annotate the code that is running with green.

Comment: I am trying to instrument .war files using cobertura-2.0.3. When I run cobertura-instrument.bat. I get Exception in thread "main" Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.